# How to add nuget package for offline tfs build task

Tags: build, tfs, nuget-package, offline

I have an TFS build server without internet access. There is a build definition with Nuget Restore step. It's configured as I understand to take package from Destination directory folder:

[image]

At least all old packages is at this folder.

I have to add some new packages, but when I add it to this folder build process doesn't find them:

```
2024-03-25T01:17:13.1908678Z Restoring NuGet package System.Text.Json.5.0.0.
2024-03-25T01:17:13.1908678Z Restoring NuGet package System.Text.Encodings.Web.5.0.0.
2024-03-25T01:17:13.1918682Z Restoring NuGet package System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.5.0.0.
2024-03-25T01:17:13.1928680Z Restoring NuGet package System.Buffers.4.5.1.
2024-03-25T01:17:13.2258701Z Missing $(NuGetRestorePath)\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\5.0.0\system.text.json.nuspec
2024-03-25T01:17:13.2258701Z Missing $(NuGetRestorePath)\.nuget\packages\system.buffers\4.5.1\system.buffers.nuspec
2024-03-25T01:17:13.2268678Z Missing $(NuGetRestorePath)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.bcl.asyncinterfaces\5.0.0\microsoft.bcl.asyncinterfaces.nuspec
2024-03-25T01:17:13.2268678Z Missing $(NuGetRestorePath)\.nuget\packages\system.numerics.vectors\4.5.0\system.numerics.vectors.nuspec
2024-03-25T01:17:13.2278699Z Missing $(NuGetRestorePath)\.nuget\packages\system.text.encodings.web\5.0.0\system.text.encodings.web.nuspec
2024-03-25T01:17:13.2288692Z Missing $(NuGetRestorePath)\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\5.0.0\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.nuspec
2024-03-25T01:17:13.2308680Z Missing $(NuGetRestorePath)\.nuget\packages\system.memory\4.5.4\system.memory.nuspec
2024-03-25T01:17:13.2318684Z Restoring NuGet package System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4.
2024-03-25T01:17:13.2318684Z Missing $(NuGetRestorePath)\.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks.extensions\4.5.4\system.threading.tasks.extensions.nuspec
2024-03-25T01:19:19.3462514Z WARNING: Unable to find version '4.5.0' of package 'System.Numerics.Vectors'.
2024-03-25T01:19:19.3462514Z   $(NuGetRestorePath)\.nuget\packages\: Package 'System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0' is not found on source '$(NuGetRestorePath)\.nuget\packages\'.
2024-03-25T01:19:19.3462514Z   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
2024-03-25T01:19:19.3462514Z   An error occurred while sending the request.
2024-03-25T01:19:19.3462514Z   Unable to connect to the remote server
2024-03-25T01:19:19.3462514Z   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 13.107.246.67:443
2024-03-25T01:19:19.3462514Z
```

How I must to add packages at this case? Maybe I must to register it anywhere? Or .nuspec file is necessary? If so how I can make it?

Answer (score 1):

The `Destination directory` in `nuget restore` task is NOT the package source, it's the `folder where the packages are installed`.

[image]

As per your error, the pacakges are missing understand path `$(NuGetRestorePath)\.nuget\packages\`, so what you done is directly copy the packages into the folder.

For restore from `local`, actually you can use `nuget.config`. specify local source feed as sample below, put the config in the project folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="localsource" value="path/to/local/packages" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

in `nuget restore` task, you can specify the nuget.config as source.

[image]

The packages will be installed to the destination directory specified(c:\check):

[image]

If you don't specify `Destination directory`, the packages will be restored into a packages/ folder alongside the selected solution, package.config, or project.json.

Please check the doc [NuGetCommand@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-command-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#restore) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes very likely .nuspec file is necessary.

As solution I copy packages from my local machine C:\Users.nuget\packages\ to TFS server $(NuGetRestorePath).nuget\packages\